# Dota 2: Is CK viable on Offlane?

Tags: dota-2

I planned to return to DoTA 2 after a-half year hiatus. I might planned to use CK, PA or Viper that I can play well.

Since the last update, is CK viable to use in Offlane? Is any thing required to prevent ganking on CK?

Answer (score 2):

No, the hero has no escape mechanism which is key on offlaners. He cannot fight a trilane nor transition well with no farm.

Play CK as a roaming 4 and abuse his strong stun if you must.
Otherwise an aggro duo/tri is also good.

Answer (score 0):

Usually offlane heroes have an escape mechanism, CK doesn't have that. Offlane heroes benefit from getting experience, while gold is a bonus. CK, on the other hand, requires items to function well, hence gold is more important than experience.